# ASP.NET Core SignalR Wait / Result blocks

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, signalr, task

While designing a web API I came to SignalR which seems to fit my demands having a persistent connection to the server which holds a state for the current client.

My problem is the "async - only" api.

I rarely use TPL and I used to synchronize async calls with `.Wait()` or `.Result()` which (I learned is bad practice) in a separate thread by message pumping and this worked for me so far.

I understood when using await, my code below can be executed on the same thread context as the ...Async() function which can cause a deadlock when using `.Wait()` or `.Result` when the same thread context is used.

But find the code below:

```
AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
private void Invoke()
{
  Thread s = new Thread(() =>
  {
    Task t = hubConnection.InvokeAsync("Sum", 5, 7);

    t.Wait();

    are.Set();
  });

  s.Start();

  are.WaitOne();
```

`Invoke()` is called from UI thread. This call starts a complete new thread in which the async call is performed. But also here, when calling `.Wait()` everything is blocked.

If we replace the SignalR call

```
 Task t = hubConnection.InvokeAsync();
 t.Wait();
```

by

```
Task t = Task.Delay(5000);
t.Wait();
```

it works as expected.

Can someone solve this puzzle for me? And how can I make real synchronous calls to that SignalR api

**[Edit]**

Meanwhile tried include `async / await`

See this code

```
AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
private void Invoke()
{

  Thread s = new Thread(async () =>
  {
    await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("Sum", 5, 7);

    are.Set();
  });

  s.Start();

  are.WaitOne();
}
```

This case also causes deadlock. How is this still possible?
I think there must be a bug.

Comment: `how can I make real synchronous calls` Why not learn `async`/`await` instead?

Comment: @Stephen Cleary: please find my edit using ```async / await``` still with deadlock.

Comment: You're creating a new thread and blocking on it.

Comment: Why does ```await``` not block when remove ```are.WaitOne()```. It seems invoking thread blocks the new thread ```s```. That makes no sense to me.